# Is "wish/if only + I/we + would " possible?

Tags: sentence-construction

https://taylorenglish.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/wish-if-only-form-function-and-meaning-present-and-past-usage/ From this site,  I have read that the first person singular or plural pronoun
cannot follow wish/if only and directly preceed would +
infinitive. So it is not possible to say :

I wish I/we would go to the cinema this weekend.

Here, the correct form is:

I wish I/we could go to the cinema this weekend.

My question is : why is it not possible?  what's the problem with "would" ?

Comment: Be careful with overgeneralization like that. [wish would have](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Abooks.google.com++%22I+wish+I+would%22&btnG=&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new) is perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

We use **wish** + **subject** + **would** to express regret about an action that a third party is unwilling to perform. But you yourself have the ability to perform that action since you are the subject of both **wish** and **would**.

> The subject of **wish** cannot be the same as the subject of **would** as this would be illogical. We cannot therefore have **I wish** + **I would**.

- I wish I would go there. - *is like regretting that you are unwilling to go there.*

Notice that with "**could**" you express a desire with the regret for inability or impossibility:

- I wish I could go there. - *You have a desire to go there but there's something preventing it.*

**I wish I would** is volitional, and is used in unusual cases, for instance in the negative.

- I wish I wouldn't throw money in the air. *- You have some sort of addiction to spending your money that you can't give up so easily.*